# Can't log in (unexpected EOF in .profile)

Tags: login-screen, .profile

I am stuck in a login loop because of this error.

I've seen a few threads about this matter but none helped.

I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, when I log in it shows me two errors:

```
-bash: /home/imight/.profile: line 19 unexpected EOF while looking for matching
-bash: /home/imight/.profile: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 2):

The message basically says that there is something wrong with the file `.profile` in your home directory. You will either have to correct this error or to remove the file.

So use a Live CD or USB and boot from that. When the system is up, use "Try Ubuntu" and open the hard drive. You'll find it normally in the sidebar or you can open a terminal and enter `ls /media`. Your mounted hard drive lives there. Navigate to `home/imight`. The whole path is `/media/SOMETHING/home/imight`, where `SOMETHING` depends on the layout of your drive. The best option is to rename the file `.profile` to some other name. But you can also open the file and see if you can find the error. Once you've spotted it you might be able to correct it.

After you renamed the file or corrected it you can reboot into your system. Now you'll be able to login.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `.profile` file and logging in again.

Comment: how do i do that? can i erase .profile file?

Comment: try `ls -l ~imight/.profile` to check the ownership of the file and use rm command accordingly to remove it.

Comment: Rather than removing `.profile`, it's better to *rename* it. For example: `cd ~imight && mv .profile .profile.old` Then no information is lost and the file can be restored later.

Comment: @ArushSalil  @EliahKagan What is `~imight`?

Comment: @mook765 The OP's home directory, `/home/imight`.

Comment: @PerlDuck Ah, something new for me, I'd simply type `~` , I haven't seen that before, so I thought it was a funny kind of typo...

Comment: @mook765 Just `~` is _your_ home directory and `~bob` is _bob's_ home directory. Works with any username. See https://askubuntu.com/q/656869/504066