# How does using the tilde work as a shortcut to my home directory?

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I was confused, trying to copy some files from one PC to another. I have it figured out, but the syntax is still confusing to me.
This works:

```
scp ~/Desktop/Volenteer.png jay@server.ip:~j0h/b
```

which puts `Volenteer.png` in the folder `/home/j0h/b`.  However, this doesn't work:

```
scp ~Desktop/Volenteer.png     jay@server.ip:~j0h/b
```

This also fails, giving an exit status 1 file not found:

```
scp ~/Desktop/Volenteer.png     jay@server.ip:~/j0h/b
```

As does this:

```
scp ~Desktop/Volenteer.png     jay@server.ip:~j0h/b
```

So clearly, there is some difference between `~` and `~/`
That difference is the presence of `/`

```
$~/
bash: /home/j0h/: Is a directory
$ ~
bash: /home/j0h: Is a directory
```

So why in scp, does the `~` resolve to `~/` ?
That is a guess, I cant verify that's what is happening. 
But it seems inconsistent, and therefore confusing. 
Is this a bug in scp? or is there something about tilde I am missing?

Comment: Just a side note here, it's spelled "volunteer", with a "u" instead of an "e" :)

Comment: I'm a liberal speller.

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/q/972319/295286

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`~` is your home directory.

`~foo` is the home directory of user `foo`, if such a user exists, or just a directory named `~foo`, if that user doesn't exist.

---

Hence, in:

```
scp ~Desktop/Volenteer.png     jay@server.ip:~j0h/b
```

`~Desktop` will expand to home directory of user `Desktop`, if such a user exists (and it usually does not), or be just `~Desktop` (a path which usually does not exist either).

---

In:

```
scp ~/Desktop/Volenteer.png     jay@server.ip:~/j0h/b
```

`~/j0h` will expand to a directory named `j0h` in `jay`'s home directory, which, again, is unlikely to exist.

---

It's not `~` and `~/` where the difference occurs, but in `~` and `~foo`.

---

Additionally, `~` can also be used for directory history navigation:

- `~-` is the previous working directory (like `$OLDPWD`)
- `~+` is the current working directory (like `$PWD`)

This is not applicable to `scp`, since you don't get to change directories in the middle of an `scp` operation.

And if you use [`pushd` and `popd`](https://askubuntu.com/a/703156/158442) to maintain a directory stack, `~N` and `~+N` would be the *`N`* th directory in the directory stack, as seen in the output of `dirs`. `~-N` would be the *`N`* th directory from the end (counting from zero, in both cases). For example:

```
$ for i in etc usr var tmp; do pushd /$i; done
/etc ~/.vim
/usr /etc ~/.vim
/var /usr /etc ~/.vim
/tmp /var /usr /etc ~/.vim

$ dirs
/tmp /var /usr /etc ~/.vim
```

Then, the directories in the stack can be accessed using:

```
/tmp /var /usr /etc ~/.vim
  ~0   ~1   ~2   ~3     ~4
 ~+0  ~+1  ~+2  ~+3    ~+4
 ~-4  ~-3  ~-2  ~-1    ~-0 
  ~+   ~-
```

Comment: So, `~+` is always equivalent to `.` then, is that right?  Seems redundant.

Comment: @Wildcard well, not exactly. `~+` and `~-` use the values of `$PWD` and `$OLDPWD`, which are absolute paths. `.` is always a relative path. So, if there's a command which changes the current working directory when executing, it will see the new path for `.`, where the path expanded by `~-` will remain the same. `tar -C` is an example, though I admit I can't think of a good use for `~+`. `$PWD` would be just as good, except that you don't need to quote `~+/foo/bar` if `$PWD` contains spaces.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it.  Actually that's a good example use case right there: Some commands refuse to operate on relative paths for security reasons; with such commands you can't use `./filename` but can use `"$PWD/filename"` or more simply `~+/filename`.  (And some commands will *work* on relative pathnames but there is a functional difference, such as `ln` or `tar`.)

Answer (score 22):

Have a read through of the [GNU documentation for Bash Tilde Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) (as I should have before my first iteration of this answer).

`~/Desktop` and `~j0h` are doing fundamentally different things, which explains why `~Desktop` doesn't work:

- A plain `~` is substituted for your current `$HOME` environment variable, set on login. So `~` resolves to `/home/oli` for me, and `~/Desktop` reads as `/home/oli/Desktop`. This is where you see the tilda being used most.
- `~username` resolves to the home of **that user**, as set in `/etc/passwd`. So `~oli` resolves to `/home/oli`, `~j0h` might resolve to `/home/j0h` but not neccessarily, your homedir can be anywhere.
- `~not-a-username` doesn't resolve. Because `Desktop` is not a user, `~Desktop` isn't substituted. It is taken literally as a file or path named `~Desktop` (which doesn't exist here).

And needless to say, this is all happening remotely (it'd be useless in `scp` if it were replaced with local values). This works because Bash won't substitute `~...` if it's preceded by anything but whitespace.

Comment: What does `getent passwd bin` say?

Comment: "bin" is a system user on most Linux machines, with a home directory of /bin.

Comment: The failure to expand `~dir` is consistent with the GNU docs: "...the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible *login name*... If the login name is invalid, or the tilde expansion fails, the word is left unchanged." Here, `dir` is not the name of a user on this system, so it is left unchanged.

Comment: Thanks all. I should probably *read* the links I post :)

Answer (score 4):

The symbol `~` is used as a shortcut for `/home/user` in `bash`, so in the case of `~/Desktop/Volenteer.png` it is shorthand for `/home/user/Desktop/Volenteer.png`.

So as you can see the `/`, as always, shows an new level in the file system hierarchy.

Comment: only half right, its a shorthand for the $HOME environment variable. `~{user}/` could just be any random path as set by the passwd(5) database file. While yes, the filesytem.org standards does place regular users in /home this is not the case with every user (ie root in /root, and services in /var/... or older unixies using /usr instead of /home)

Comment: DwightSpencer is correct. I maintain several servers where the users are in    /usr/{CLIENTNAME}/home/ and are shared over several inhouse and remote systems (all point to that directory) so only 1 system needs to be maintained. And ~ points to that directory ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind eek. I must protest at this sacrilegious misuse of `/usr`.

Comment: @muru hey it was not MY call >:-D It was a left over from SCO D:

Comment: Honestly I liked the use of /usr for all things user since that's what it originally meant. What I find these days is the more sacrilegious misuse of /usr/bin as a grand unified dumping ground of all binaries(sys,user,sysop) outside of the base binutils. After all /usr was meant as all things users have access to pulled from a nfs mount while /usr/local was the local user space with /sbin as sysop binaries and /bin system binaries. I get that /home can be a different partition but so can /usr/home/... keeping it in /usr keeps it as user namespace both in policy, implementation, and mindset.

Answer (score 3):

`~` is shorthand for the environment variable `$HOME` on most c shell derivative/supporting POSIX compliant shells. the most common use for `~` is when referencing your own home directory or that of another user's home:

```
cd ~ # ie shell, take me to my home folder

cd ~root # i.e. shell, take me to root's home folder
```

To find the home directory for any local user on a POSIX system (UNIX, Linux, OS X, BSD) that is using the [passwd(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/passwd.5) database run awk on `/etc/passwd` like so:

```
awk -F: '{ print $1,$(NF-1) }' /etc/passwd
```

This will list each local user and their home directory.