# Bash script syntax

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to create a .sh script which will

1. execute a python file called `match_scraper.py`,
2. update a psql db as shown,
3. call a scrapy spider to execute.

When I create the .sh script how do I call those commands properly? This is what I have come up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

~Documents/dota2/dotaapi2/ python match_scraper.py 

psql dota2apidb
update games set online=1 where online is null;

~Documents/dota2/gosugamers/gosugamers/spiders/ scrapy crawl dota
```

Comment: What are `~Documents/dota2/dotaapi2/` and `~Documents/dota2/gosugamers/gosugamers/spiders/` supposed to be? The directories containing the scripts? I'd guess you want to do `cd ~/Documents/dota2/gosugamers/gosugamers/spiders/` (and similarly for the other one), instead. (Note: slash `/` after `~`: http://askubuntu.com/q/656869/158442)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make sure each line/part of your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script work in a shell (outside of a script). I cannot tell if yours will so you'll have to check that yourself.

And to execute a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script you need `python` BEFORE the path to the script

Also:

- `~` is a shortcut to the home directory of the **current** user
- `~asdf` is a shortcut to the home directory for the **asdf** user
- `~/Documents` is the path to the `Documents` folder in the home directory of the **current** user
- `~Documents` is looking for the home directory of the **Directory** user which is invalid unless you have a user called Directory

As @muru pointed out, you probably meant ~/Documents. So your bash script would probably look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

python ~/Documents/dota2/dotaapi2/match_scraper.py 

psql dota2apidb
update games set online=1 where online is null;

python ~/Documents/dota2/gosugamers/gosugamers/spiders/scrapy crawl dota
```

Again, I do not know if this will work since I have no clue if each line will work. For example, does `python ~/Documents/dota2/gosugamers/gosugamers/spiders/scrapy crawl dota` actually work when you run it on the command line?

And I do not know [psql](/questions/tagged/psql) but I suspect you need to pass it some command line paramater to get it to run that `update...` command?

Comment: The 'scrapy crawl dota' command works from the terminal if I am in the file path of ...gosugamers/gosugamers

Comment: Well, as long as you can do things from a shell then you'll be able to include in your bash script.