# Unable to change directory to cd: /Downloads error message No such file or directory

Tags: directory

I am unable to change my directory to /home/username/Downloads. I keep getting the error message no such file or directory. What could I possibly be doing wrong as I've tried everything.

Comment: Welcome, what's the actual command you are using? [edit] the question adding it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does using the tilde work as a shortcut to my home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656869/how-does-using-the-tilde-work-as-a-shortcut-to-my-home-directory)

Comment: From the title of your question, I wonder if you typed 'cd: /Downloads'? The command given in the answer is the correct one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is an abbreviation for your own user's home directory, and you can also use either `cd` by itself or `cd ~` to navigate to your home directory.

To change directories to your Downloads directory open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Comment: thanks. this worked for me