# /home/username/ Directory Not Found Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: home-directory

For some reason, the /home/username/ directory doesn't exist. I can't find it with the terminal, I can't find it in the files, it simply doesn't exist to my testing.

Is this normal, or is something wrong with my system?

Comment: Just a question, is `username` really your current username ? Whats the output of `echo $USER $HOME` ?

Comment: No, username isn't my real username, however I tried both replacing username with my current username and using username, both didn't work.

`echo $HOME` gives me `/home/[my username here]`, however whenever I go to that directory, it doesn't bring me to that directory.

Comment: It's really odd that you didn't have your home directory created on desktop installation, try this `mkhomedir_helper (your_username)` taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/546090/253251).

Comment: @Liso I used the command, but I didn't get an output and I tried finding the directory again, still didn't find it.

Comment: How exactly you 'tried finding the directory' ? Is it a read-only system ? If so refer to this to determine whether it is in fact ro system https://serverfault.com/a/349025.

Comment: @Liso I went into the search bar feature on the files app, which I found nothing, but after a bit of thinking I went to terminal and typed `open $HOME` which brought me to my normal Home section.
For some reason, now my apps detect it despite nothing changing. I don't exactly know what happened, but thanks for the help. XD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change directory to cd: /Downloads error message No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366477/unable-to-change-directory-to-cd-downloads-error-message-no-such-file-or-direc)

Answer (score 0):

if you come from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383022/creating-a-wine-prefix), you have to take note about "/home/username/" path. In some situations, points to "replace the word username from path using your session's username". Please follow the original question's thread.

Answer (score 0):

It is very normal that a directory `/home/username` may not exist. I also do not have one.

Typically, directories under `/home` are the home directories of users created on the system. For a user with login name e.g. `Pokegamer129`, a directory `/home/Pokegamer129` would exist on the system. Only if there is a user with the login name `username` we do expect the existence of a directory `/home/username`, otherwise not.

So do not worry if that directory does not exist if no such user `username`  is registered on the system.